# Handling Multiple POST Requests in one PHP file or Separate

Tags: php, ios, apache, postgresql, post

I am new to PHP as you may be able to tell from the question.
What I have is an iOS application that accesses a database via an apache server using a php front end. I have managed to get a user inserted into the database using a POST on a php script called NewUser.php

The thing I am struggling with is how to organize the files and whether or not I need multiple php scripts for each query I want to run on the database or I am able to handle each different POST request in the same script?

As I said I am new to the concept of PHP. If anyone could point me in the right direction to maybe a tutorial or give me some pointers on here that would be great!

Disco

Comment: PHP is your programming language, how to organize files is up to you. There is no a real guideline. You may interested to look an architectural pattern like MVC: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, you can handle more type of POST requests in one script.

For example script name is action.php and inside is code:

```
switch ($_POST['action']) {
   case 'insert_user':
       // code for inserting new user
       break;
   case 'delete_user':
       // code for deleteing user
       break;
   // and so on ...
}
```

and when are you doing POST request you will have to add parameter `action` which one will indetify the correct action.

```
POST /action.php HTTP/1.1
Some headers

action=insert_user&name=John&surname=Doe....
```