# GET POST or two seperate files for handling requests

Tags: php, mysql, database, backend

before everything my question is not Duplicate of [Handling Multiple POST Requests in one PHP file or Separate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6663116/handling-multiple-post-requests-in-one-php-file-or-separate).

i wanna develop a RESTful backend and i'm a little bit confused in case i'm going to explain below :

e.g i have a Schedule table in my DB. then there is two scenario here, whether i'm reading and fetching data(GET) or i'm setting or updating them(POST). till now i would have created two separate files named (setSchedule - getSchedule) and i'd sent request to the one i needed and i was never concerned about request type(get-post).

but i there is one other way that there is just one file/url (Schedule) but it acts differently based on the request type(GET-POST). if its GET its fetch data and send them back or it POST and it will update DB.

my question is that which approach is better? ( from better i mean it's more common- more modular - more efficient - more easier to handle ...).

Comment: Use MVC, use a router that routes to two different controller methods. One for get and one for post.

Comment: I don't understand why you don't just use different identifiers to, well, differentiate between the two?

Comment: @bassxzero i've never used routers before, do u mean making two different files(first approach) and just choose which one to use using router?

Comment: @Martin could you please explain more

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/routing